# I'm trying to create a bookmark bot that DMs a message to the user who reacts with an emoji

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So say if the user reacts to any message with the "bookmark" emoji, I want the bot to send that message via a DM to the user.

This is my first bot, so a little help would be appreciated. Here's what I have so far - I just want the bot to simply recognise the bookmark emoji for now and reply in the channel, then I'll build on that to send a DM to the user.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Color, Embed, Member, Message, RawReactionActionEvent, User
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    
bot = commands.Bot("!")

@staticmethod
def _payload_has_bookmark_emoji(payload: RawReactionActionEvent) -> bool:
  #Test if the RawReactionActionEvent payload contains a bookmark emoji.
  if str(payload.raw.emoji) == "":
    return True


@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload: RawReactionActionEvent) -> None:
  
  channel = discord.utils.get(self.bot.get_all_channels(), id=payload.channel_id)
  message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
  member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)

  if self._payload_has_bookmark_emoji(payload) is True:
    print("Hello!")
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Running this code and testing by reacting to a message with the bookmark emoji does nothing, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is causing your problem:

from the discord API reference for `on_raw_reaction_add`:

> Called when a message has a reaction added. Unlike on_reaction_add(), this is called regardless of the state of the internal message cache. This requires Intents.reactions to be enabled.

Here's how you enable Intents.reactions:

```py
intents=discord.Intents.default()
intents.reactions=True
client=discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also, make sure that you checked off the right permissions in OAuth on the developer portal when you connected it to your server. For debugging, if you own the server you can give the bot the admin role and connect it to the server with login permissions.

Here's code I've used to DM a user(for you to use later):

```py
DMChannel=user.dm_channel
if DMchannel is None:
    DMchannel=await user.create_dm()
await DMchannel.send('DM goes here')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, helped a lot and now it's working! On to the next problem :)